# How do I turn a proc print result of eigenvectors into a SAS data table

Tags: sas

I want to sort my table of eigenvectors into ascending order. In order to do that I  think need to turn my table of eigenvectors into a SAS data table. How do I do that? Below is part of the code I used to created my eigenvectors.

```
proc princomp data = test;
ID$ name$ DOB$ Job_Title$ Salary$
{DATA IS INSERTED HERE}
run;
```

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

Comment: @Reeza Thanks, this has helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `outstat=` option in your `proc princomp` statement:

[OUTSTAT= Option](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/statug_princomp_sect004.htm#statug.princomp.outstatopt)

> OUTSTAT=*SAS-data-set*
>
> creates an output SAS data set that contains means, standard deviations, number of observations, correlations or covariances, **eigenvalues, and eigenvectors**. If you specify the COV option, the data set is TYPE=COV or TYPE=UCOV, depending on the NOINT option, and it contains covariances; otherwise, the data set is TYPE=CORR or TYPE=UCORR, depending on the NOINT option, and it contains correlations. If you specify the PARTIAL statement, the OUTSTAT= data set contains R squares as well.

Comment: @Stu_Sztukowski Hi thanks for your answer. Just to clarify am I supposed to write Outstat = test, just before I write run?

Comment: `proc princomp data=test outstat=stats` will produce an output statistic dataset called "stats"